# Explain the importance of Bitcoin Hash Rate using cpuminer

Tags: hashpower, c, cpuminer

I need thoroughly explanations about Bitcoin Hash Rate beyond the trivial ones like:

> "Hashrate" refers to the total combined computational power that is
> being used to mine and process transactions on a Proof-of-Work
> blockchain.

I will use two [cpuminer](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer/blob/master/cpu-miner.c) functions to formulate my question:

[share_result](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer/blob/master/cpu-miner.c#L681) and [applog](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer/blob/master/util.c#L69). (applog is called by share_result, so it is importante to include it here.)

(look the functions at the bottom and then return to the question)

I have tried to understand the code but I haven't found any explanation where the variable **`hashrate`** will be used.

Please, explain this detail.

```
static void share_result(int result, const char *reason)
{
    char s[345];
    double hashrate;
    int i;

    hashrate = 0.;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&stats_lock);
    for (i = 0; i < opt_n_threads; i++)
        hashrate += thr_hashrates[i];
    result ? accepted_count++ : rejected_count++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stats_lock);
    
    sprintf(s, hashrate >= 1e6 ? "%.0f" : "%.2f", 1e-3 * hashrate);
    applog(LOG_INFO, "accepted: %lu/%lu (%.2f%%), %s khash/s %s",
           accepted_count,
           accepted_count + rejected_count,
           100. * accepted_count / (accepted_count + rejected_count),
           s,
           result ? "(yay!!!)" : "(booooo)");

    if (opt_debug && reason)
        applog(LOG_DEBUG, "DEBUG: reject reason: %s", reason);
}



void applog(int prio, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);

#ifdef HAVE_SYSLOG_H
    if (use_syslog) {
        va_list ap2;
        char *buf;
        int len;
        
        va_copy(ap2, ap);
        len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, ap2) + 1;
        va_end(ap2);
        buf = alloca(len);
        if (vsnprintf(buf, len, fmt, ap) >= 0)
            syslog(prio, "%s", buf);
    }
#else
    if (0) {}
#endif
    else {
        char *f;
        int len;
        time_t now;
        struct tm tm, *tm_p;

        time(&now);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&applog_lock);
        tm_p = localtime(&now);
        memcpy(&tm, tm_p, sizeof(tm));
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&applog_lock);

        len = 40 + strlen(fmt) + 2;
        f = alloca(len);
        sprintf(f, "[%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d] %s\n",
            tm.tm_year + 1900,
            tm.tm_mon + 1,
            tm.tm_mday,
            tm.tm_hour,
            tm.tm_min,
            tm.tm_sec,
            fmt);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&applog_lock);
        vfprintf(stderr, f, ap);    /* atomic write to stderr */
        fflush(stderr);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&applog_lock);
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```